# Why does the bot message not send?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, botframework, botconnector

I am using c9 as my dev environment and when running under development the bot does not actually send the message through even though sending.batch was called.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
  session.send('Alec said ' + session.message.text);
});
function status(request,reply){
 connector.listen(request.raw.req,request.raw.res);
 return reply("ok");
}
  if (useEmulator) {
   var restify = require('restify');
   var server = restify.createServer();
   server.listen(8080, function() {
     console.log('test bot endpont at http://localhost:8080/api/messages');
   });
   server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());  
} else {
  module.exports = { default: connector.listen() }
}
```

That is the code use to implement server, as taken from azure bot setup, i edited the port as c9 cant use the default port.

[results after sending a message through emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdkSl.jpg)

Comment: It looks like we're missing some context here but seems like you're following some guide. Could you reference the guide you're following?

Answer (score 0):

It seems using cloud 9 server would not allow me to send out a response message my solution was to ssh into my own server at which point the app would work as intended.